# NTFS backup image won't mount

Tags: mount, backup, disk-image

I made an image of my NTFS partition before I formatted, but now it won't mount. I'm pretty sure I've mounted this image before.

```
root@z:/var/backup# mkdir Storage-disk
root@z:/var/backup# mount Storage-disk.img Storage-disk
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read vcn 0x2: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/var/backup/Storage-disk.img': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

I've tried running ntfsfix on the image, but no dice.

```
root@z:/var/backup# ntfsfix Storage-disk.img
Mounting volume... pread: Input/output error
Failed to calculate number of free MFTs: Input/output error.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors...
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
pread: Input/output error
Failed to calculate number of free MFTs: Input/output error.
Remount failed: Input/output error.
```

Needless to say, I really want this backup to work :-( Please help!

**Update:** `ntfsmount` says this:

```
root@z:/var/backup# ntfsmount Storage-disk.img Storage-disk
pread: Input/output error
Failed to calculate number of free MFTs: Input/output error.
Failed to mount '/var/backup/Storage-disk.img': Input/output error.
NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
made to NTFS by this software.
Mount failed.
```

How do I run `chkdsk /f` on an image? Do I have to create a partition and write the image on it? How do I do that?

Comment: If you run `cat Storage-disk.img >/dev/null`, do you get any input/output error? If so, I'm afraid your disk is dying, and you should copy all your data off it (`dd_rescue` will help) before doing anything else.

Comment: Nice tip, but it executed with no errors. Do you have more suggestions?

Comment: Just to be sure, check the `dmesg` or `/var/log/messages` for possible indications that something is wrong with your disk. Otherwise the image might just be damaged.

Comment: Can't find anything relevant in neither. So, how do I repair it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried running a scandisk in windows? That's how I've always fixed faulty partitions.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I make a partition of it so Windows can scan it?

Comment: @Znarkus: You could try to move it to a partition from which you can access it in Windows and using something like DaemonTools to mount the image.

Comment: NICE! Installed a nifty application (evaluation) called Mount Image Pro. It could mount the partitions images without any problem :-)

Comment: Hm. But I can't seem to access some of the files. How do I mount a dd image with Daemon tools, or do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This could also be due to an error in the filesystem containing the image (basically the device on which `storage-disk.img` is stored). Did you try checking that device with fsck ?

If that is successful, the following are the options :

1. Make a copy (using cp or [ntfsclone](http://man.linux-ntfs.org/ntfsclone.8.html)) and try to mount it with [force option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6819206&postcount=2)
2. Use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)
3. Repair via ChkDsk by running windows on VM.

Comment: I now ran `xfs_check`, but it didn't detect any errors on the partition `storage-disk.img` is stored.

Comment: In that case there are 2 options

1. If you cannot run windows in a VM, then you can try to make a copy of the image and try to force-mount it.

2. If you can run windows in a VM, *try* to use chkdsk to repair it.

Let me know which is easier for you, I will expand my answer.

Comment: Do I need a Windows VM? I've got plenty of Windows machines around. If I can't get something like Daemon tools to work, I was thinking of `dd` the image back to a "real" partition on a disk. Do you know how to do that, or do you have any other suggestions?