# Write dd image to disk

Tags: backup, dd

Before I installed Ubuntu on my old computer, I took backups of both partitions with dd. Long story short: I now want to restore these two files, `XP.dd` and `Storage.dd`, to the computer again. How do I do this?

Thanks!

This question is related: [NTFS backup image wont mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4584/ntfs-backup-image-wont-mount)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making full disk image with DD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509639/making-full-disk-image-with-dd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When people use `dd` to backup an image of a partition, they often fail to backup the partition table as well. If you didn't, you can try creating partitions of similar sizes with `fdisk` and set the partition flags appropriately. Then `dd` them back and run whatever disk checking utility suits the partition in question from a bootable CD.

Slightly more detailed:

```
$ ls -l imagename #to get the size  
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdX
```

**Options:**

- `n`: adds a new partition (follow the prompts, make a modestly larger partition and resize if the fix works).
- `t`: sets the partition type in the partition table.
- `w`: writes the changes to the disk.
- `m`: lists options as the program informs you.

Then run:

```
sudo dd if=imagename of=/dev/sdXY
```

Run the appropriate disk check utility after the `dd` restore is complete.
There are better ways to do this, they aren't horribly relevant and are overly complicated.

Comment: When do one need to backup the partition table/MBR? Initially I only needed to backup the OS partition

Comment: I back up the WHOLE disk with a dd if=/dev/sdX as opposed to sdXY...that way I can treat it like a disk instead of worrying with complications relating to re-integration later....I can always delete partitions I don't need and resize.  I would rather have it and not need it, than need it and not have it.

Comment: additional note: there are multiple questions on this particular forum about difficulties in mounting individual partition images...i have none of these problems with my method.  it is unnecessary, but it is simple.  i like simplicity.

Comment: I created two partitions, `dd`'d the images to them, but then I'm stuck trying to install MBR/bootloader. Do you have a suggestion how to do this? :)

Comment: http://www.backuphowto.info/backup-mbr-linux

Comment: to back up: dd if=/dev/sda of=~/mbr.img bs=512 count=1

Comment: to restore: dd of=/dev/sda if=~/yourfile bs=512 count=1

Comment: Don't I need to have backuped up my MBR for that to work?

Comment: We can't possibly be talking about the same box for Nov of last year...The solution I would use in that case is to do a minimalist install from alternate to restore the boot loader after doing the fdisk stuff.  Then do the dd restore.

Comment: Oops it looks like you're trying to restore windows...boot from the XP ISO and run fdisk /FIXMBR

Answer (score 4):

I think you should only *dd back* the img data to partiton.
example(boot with live ubuntu, expected /dev/hda1 is the restoreable partition, unmount it first, if it mounted):

```
# umount /dev/hda1
# dd if=/path/to/image.dd of=/dev/hda1
# mount /dev/hda1 /path/to/mount
```

After you checked the data, reboot, or set correctly your fstab.
Please give more info, for more help!

Comment: Isn't `/dev/hda1` the first partition? Mustn't I create that first? What info do you need?

Comment: Yes, this is the first, but it is only an example. 

You sure, that you must create it first, but I thought that you did it, or you backuped the /dev/hda (the partition table).

I thought, you may write, what partition is that, and ask concrate question about this problem.