# Making full disk image with DD

Tags: 14.04, backup

it is possible to make a full disk image with running ubuntu with following command:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/image_name
```

After i make it, how can i restore that image on a crushed system?

Comment: Three things I would suggest. One: do it from a live CD. Two: make sure the image you create is not on the same volume as the one being copied. Three: this will probably only work if both hard drives are the same size.

Comment: How can i do that from liveCD? AFAIK from liveCD you can't do any write actions.

Comment: @Heihachi why would you not be able to write to a harddisk from a live DVD?

Comment: I would suggest using a USB hard drive as the location to sent the image

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Boot from the live cd. Mount your destination media to (say) /mnt.

```
dd if=/dev/sdXXX of=/mnt/mybackup.ddimg
```

To restore:

```
dd if=/mnt/mybackup.ddimg of=/dev/sdXXX
```

The destination drive should be the same size or bigger than the original.

---

A better way is using tar.

Mount the source to /mnt, mount the destination to /home (say)

```
tar cvfpz /home/mybackup.tar.gz /mnt
```

This can then be restored to any size drive:

```
tar xvfpz /home/mybackup.tar.gz
```

(After mounting source to /home and destination to /mnt.)

Then just install grub.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to [hatterman's great answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/509689/2770) you can compress the image as it's taken using `gzip` like this:

```
dd if=/dev/sdx | gzip > /mnt/mybackup.ddimg.gz
```

Comment: note that this might require gzip to run as root