# Dual boot grub rescue

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue

I deleted a partition. When i restarted my computer i had an interface showing this message: "error no such partition.
Grub rescue>"
I don't know if the partition i've deleted was the one where ubuntu were installed (if so im dead. All my important projects are inside) or it was only storing the grub files.
Note that i have a dual boot.
Who can please help me save both my linux and windows please!

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info But if you need to restore partition then testdisk may be able to do that. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step But did you miss this before making any major change? discussion of alternatives/strategy backups
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Answer (score 0):

Hum,  not really a question, so this is not really an answer. Don't despair. Get an external USB harddrive with a lot of free space. Use an Ubuntu live CD or USB key to boot your computer, then make a full image of your hard drive on the external harddrive. for example, use the instructions in the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509639/making-full-disk-image-with-dd) (use `dd`, not `tar`). Then, and only then, use tools like [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the deleted partitions.

If you are so unlucky that testdisk can't recover the lost partitions, [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) can still be used to recover some of the files. This is however a last resort, as photorec cannot restore file names and directory structure, nor can it make difference between a file that had been deleted and a file that was present at the time you deleted the partition.

Comment: @sudodus you edited my answer and added photorec. Photorec has **nothing** to do with testdisk. So don't let them side by side, in the same sentence. Your edit was **misleading** in the sense that it let people think testdisk and photorec are the same kind of software. I let the photorec suggestion, but with **some more explanations**. OP did not format his/her drive. The partition was deleted. testdisk is the solution, not photorec.

Comment: You are right. I should have not only added it, but also written an explanation. (For me testdisk and photorec are a couple. First try with testdisk, and if it fails, resort to photorec. They are available from the same website, https://www.cgsecurity.org/).